# How to fix an error in parsing paths using scala parser?

Tags: scala, parsing, path

I am writing a scala parser to parse the following input(x is number):
/hdfs://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx/path1/file1.jpg+1

```
  trait pathIdentifier extends RegexParsers{
     def pathIdent: Parser[String] ="""^/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+)$)""".r 
  }


class ParseExp extends JavaTokenParsers with pathIdentifier {
def expr: Parser[Any] = term~rep("+"~term | "-"~term)
def term: Parser[Any] = factor~rep("*"~factor | "/"~factor)
def factor: Parser[Any] = pathIdent | floatingPointNumber | "("~expr~")"
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
  [1.1] failure: `(' expected but `/' found
```

Can't figure out the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. First you are trying to match a string that starts with `/hfds` but your input starts with `/hdfs`. Secondly the regular expression you have will try to match the all input with the anchors you put (`^` and `$`). It means that when the parser `pathIdent` will be used, it will try to match all the input until the `Reader` has no more values to return.

In your input there is a `+1` after `.jpg` and `\w` does not match `+`, that's why you get a parse failure. So you should remove them.

Running your expression with the `expr` parser, I get:

```
[1.43] parsed: ((/hdfs://111.22.33.4:5555/path1/file1.jpg~List())~List((+~(1~List()))))
```

which is indeed a factor followed by an empty repetition of factors (`/hdfs://111.22.33.4:5555/path1/file1.jpg~List())`) followed by a repetition of a term with a `+` that is a factor (`1`) followed by an empty repetition of factors (`List((+~(1~List())))`).

Comment: @Rubbic Parsing `(/hdfs://111.22.33.4:5555/path1/file1.jpg+1)` works for me.

Comment: I am getting this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/hdfs://111.33.50.2:8020/path1/path2/file1.jpg+1' where I don't get it without parenthesis

Comment: `(/hdfs://111.22.33.4:5555/path1/file1.jpg+1)`is an `expr` within parenthesis (the third option of the `factor` parser). What is the exact input you're trying to parse?

Comment: in my bash script (that I am running the program using that and sending inputs from that ) I am reading inputs using $@ to read whatever has been sent from the command line. Do you think something can be wrong there? I also have problem if I put space between them like : 1 + 1

Comment: @Rubbic The RegexParsers should skip the whitespaces by default for you. It may come from there (the bash script). Try to print what you're parsing before, or use the `log` parser.

Comment: this is the exact input : (/hdfs://172.30.50.2:8020/xml/pen.a3d+1)+1 the program can parse it without parenthesis

Comment: @Rubbic It works and I get `[1.43] parsed: (((((~((/hdfs://172.30.50.2:8020/xml/pen.a3d~List())~List((+~(1~List())))))~))~List())~List((+~(1~List()))))` so there must be something wrong with your input (note that it lies in the grammar you defined).

Comment: thank you for helping me, using println I figured out that my bash script for some reason is not capable of reading parenthesis around my input, without it it's perfectly working with parenthesis it's not even get into the program. I need to solve that now!  Thank you for being patient with me